# Add SharePoint group to "Group Quick Luanch" using PowerShell

Tags: pnp-powershell

I'm working on a PowerShell script to set up a new site including libraries and groups. I have been able to get the groups set up, however they don't appear in the "Group Quick Launch" so you have to click "More..." to see them, which happens if you create them via the browser. Is there a way to get them in there using PowerShell?